# uitextfield text length after deleting the string

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I am having a problem I am tracking the characters typed by the user and its working  fine but as the user delete the whole message in text field and text field become empty its giving the text field text length = 1.
It should be 0 , I am not getting it all. any help

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    if (textField ==  textfield1)
    {


        NSLog(@"%d",textfield1.text.length);
        NSInteger charleft = (100 - textfield1.text.length);
        NSLog(@"The Characters left are %d",charleft);
        while(!(charleft<0))
        {

            NSString *Charlength= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",charleft];    
            Charcount.text= [ Charlength stringByAppendingFormat:@" Characters left"];
            return YES;

        }


        return NO;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int maxChars = 100;
    int charsLeft = maxChars - [textField.text length];

    if(charsLeft == 0) {
        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No more characters"
                                                         message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You have reached the character limit of %d.",maxChars]
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
    NSString *chrstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d characters remaining.",charsLeft];
    Charcount.text=chrstr;//
 NSLog(@"%@",chrstr;
},
```

It has solved my problem I connected my uitextfield with this action using editind changed option.

Answer (score 0):

You're computing `charleft` before you process the current keystroke, so the value in `Charlength.text` will be the value from *before* the current keystroke was processed. If you want `Charlength` to show the remaining characters, you need to update it after the keystroke is processed.

There's another side-effect you should be aware of here: you're not distinguishing backspace from a regular character insert. Once you exceed your threshold of 100 characters (really 101 right now, because of the bug I described) you won't ever process another character, including a backspace/delete. That means that once your user exceeds the threshold, they'll be stuck, as they won't be able to delete a character. (Try it).

Comment: Yes , You are right , I just tried and it strucks..What would be the possible solution ?

Answer (score -1):

You're probably seeing the \b character, at a complete guess.